# dnsmasq container on ARM OMV5

Tags: docker, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved, docker-compose

Would like to ask for your help with something i'm working on these days.

I'm running Openmediavault 5 on an ODROID HC2 (ARM).

It uses systemd-resolve.

I use docker containers and access everything via host_ip:port.

Was curious so i configured a Traefik container.

Initially i tried (successfully) to access my containers via host_ip\container with Traefik container, instead of host_ip:port. But had lot of issues with subfolders.

So i wanted to try with subdomains. My hostname is "dk.lan" so i will use this from now.

Of course this will never work without the proper DNS records.

To do this i tried a dnsmasq container (i prefer to not mess with dns on host, also this is not something important).

Of course port 53 was already used so i had to use another port. Not working of course.

So this is the docker-compose i'm using:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  dnsmasq:
    image: gists/dnsmasq
    container_name: dnsmasq
    #cap_add:
      #- NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - 54:53/tcp
      - 54:53/udp
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-HC2/AppData/dnsmasq/etc/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    restart: unless-stopped
  
networks:
    default:
      external:
        name: my-net
```

In "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-HC2/AppData/dnsmasq/etc/dnsmasq.d" i placed a "dnsmasq.conf" file with the following content:

```
address=/dk.lan/192.168.1.197
#resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf
listen-address=192.168.1.197
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
```

But nothing, the logs from the container says:

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.1.197: Address not available
```

P.S. My router does not support DNS editing.

What you think i could do to resolve this issue? Hope it's all clear.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: To much unnecesary and unrelated detail. Regarding the configuration, try putting the hosts for your domain in the /etc/hosts file, add the key words "expand-hosts", and "domain=dk.lan" to the /etc/dnsmasq.conf. If you want to add 127.0.0.1 as an ip address for your server, add it to /etc/hosts pointing to the host "dnsmasq" - along with the other IP address.  Add  the address=/dk.lan/127.0.0.1 and the address=/dk.lan/ 192.168.1.197 to the /etc/dnsmasq.conf file.

Comment: The issue i have here is that i can't edit the /etc/hosts file because it is overwritten by  OMV itself.

Tried to access many detail as possible because was not certain of were the issue resided.

Comment: I don't really know - try adding them to the dnsmasq configure file, e.g., "address=/dk.lan/hostname/192.168.x.x". If not, then you might have better luck on dnsmasq mailing list.